# How to focus/highlight inside toolbar elements in sencha touch2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have done application using sencha touch2 . as per requirement **i need to  focus/highlight inside the toolbar elements, when mouse is over(point to) on particular elements**. i have added pressedCls it will work once i will press, but i need to highlight on mouse over. can any tell me how to achieve this one.

Here is my code:

```
initialize:function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
    var Button1 = {
        xtype:"button",
        id: 'suvilasBtn',            
        html: '<img  height="30" width="40", src="resources/sass/images/icons/about.png" />',            
        pressedCls: 'customPressedCls',            
        scope:this
    };
    var Button2 = {
        xtype: "button",
        id: 'projectBtn',
        html: '<img  height="30" width="40", src="resources/sass/images/icons/projects.png" />',
        handler: this.onProjectsButtonTap,
        scope: this
    };
    var bottomToolbar = {
        xtype:"toolbar",
        docked:"bottom",
        scrollable: false,                      
        defaults: {
            iconMask: true,
            ui: 'plain'
        },
        layout: {
            pack : 'center',
            align: 'center'
        },
        items:[
            Button1,
            Button2
        ]
    };
    this.add([ bottomToolbar ]);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Sencha Touch intended to be used in mouseless interface. Touch :)

Comment: yes correct. thank you for your information. now i will ahead with different way. i will change html in tap of the button.